# Can't edit field directly in some cases using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am trying to edit an item of template type `/sitecore/templates/System/Forms/Fields/Input`. This item has a field named `Default Value`.

Why does this work:

```bash
$DefaultValueFieldName = "Default Value"
$myInputFieldItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
$myInputFieldItem[$DefaultValueFieldName] = "some value"
```

But this doesn't update the field?

```bash
$myInputFieldItem.$DefaultValueFieldName = "some value"
```

In addition, I get this error:

```
ERROR: The property 'Default Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set. 
at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

In fact, none of these other variations work either:

```bash
$myInputFieldItem."Default Value"= "some value"
$myInputFieldItem."Title"= "some value"
$myInputFieldItem."Css Class"= "some value"
```

Note that I CAN use this notation to edit other items successfully; just not in this case with this specific template type.

I am running the script as an administrator.

The software versions are:

- Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 5.1.0.19766
- Sitecore 9.0 Windows
- PowerShell 5.1

Comment: $myInputFieldItem.Editing.BeginEdit() are you using this one in all cases ? what user do you use when you run the script ?

Comment: I am not using `.Editing.BeginEdit()` in all cases because it's not required when doing direct field edits (e.g. `$myItem.MyField = "some val"`). I am running as admin.

Comment: Can you explain how its "not working" - as in, does it show an error message? Is there anything in the logs you can see? Is the field just not updated?

Also, is the item protected?

Comment: @RichardSeal I updated the question with the info: the field does not update and SPE throws that exception. I don't see any errors in the Sitecore logs.

Comment: Are you running as Administrator? or from any other role?

Comment: I think you need to ensure, the item you are editing is correct (maybe you filtered a wrong item, or it's an item of the wrong template). I tried it locally with `$item."Default Value" = "123"` - it works, while `$item."Default Value NOT EXISTS" = "123"` - I got the same exception as you, while `$item["Default Value NOT EXISTS"] = "123"` is more safe and does not throw an exception, even if the field does not exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the field item is retrieved in your PowerShell script, but I had this error when an item was read using Sitecore API and was not wrapped with automatic SPE properties using [`Initialize-Item`](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/indexing/initialize-item):

> The `Initialize-Item` command wraps Sitecore item with PowerShell property equivalents of fields for easy assignment of values to fields and automatic saving. This command can also be used to translate the the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem` items obtained from the Find-Item command into full Sitecore Items. The alias for the command is Wrap-Item.

See examples below.

This works:

```bash
$DefaultValueFieldName = "Default Value"
$myInputFieldItem = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/Forms/Test form/Page/Firstname"
$myInputFieldItem.$DefaultValueFieldName = "some value"
```

This doesn't work and throws the error *The property 'Default Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.* because `$myInputFieldRawItem` does not have automatic properties:

```bash
$DefaultValueFieldName = "Default Value"
$myInputFieldRawItem = [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetDatabase("master").GetItem("/sitecore/Forms/Test form/Page/Firstname")
$myInputFieldRawItem.$DefaultValueFieldName = "some value"
```

But this works:

```bash
$DefaultValueFieldName = "Default Value"
$myInputFieldRawItem = [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetDatabase("master").GetItem("/sitecore/Forms/Test form/Page/Firstname")
$myInputFieldItem = $myInputFieldRawItem | Initialize-Item
$myInputFieldItem.$DefaultValueFieldName = "some value"
```